# Angular ng-show on table row not updating

Tags: angularjs

I have a table, where each element (table row) have a boolean field in it's model, weather the problem is solved or not. I want to have a button to toggle on and off to show the elements which are 'solved' and 'unsolved'.

In the table row, it's working fine to add an ng-show to filter this:

```
<tr ng-show="problem.solved === false" ng-repeat="problem in filtered...
```

In the controller, I've added a function to toggle:

```
    $scope.toggleSolved = function() {
        if ($scope.solvedStatus === "problem.solved === false") {
            $scope.solvedStatus = "problem.solved === true";
        } else {
            $scope.solvedStatus = "problem.solved === false";
        }
    };
```

As well as a variable to hold this value:

```
$scope.solvedStatus = "problem.solved === true";
```

I then use that variable in the table row like this:

```
<tr ng-show="{{solvedStatus}}" ng-repeat="problem in filtered
```

It then shows the table-rows with the value of the variable, and I toggle this variable value with a button like this:

```
<button ng-click="toggleSolved()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Show solved</button>
```

When clicking the button, the variable change it's value correctly, but the table doesn't change. I've tried to add $scope.$digest and apply at the end of the toggle function, but get an error saying: 'apply allready in process..'

So the issue is getting the table to change which table rows to show as the variable changes.

Comment: `$scope.solvedStatus = "problem.solved === true";` why the quotes? `"problem.solved === true"` is a String which always resolves to `true` when evaluating.

Comment: they re right , no quotes .

Comment: Even without quotes it's still not correct.

Comment: `ng-click="toggleSolved(problem)"` and `$scope.toggleSolved = function(problem) {`

Comment: There are so many syntax errors it's hard to know where to even begin. Comparing a string to comparing a variable to comparing boolean? You should check out if / else comparrisons with booleans and everything to make sure you know what you're comparing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've formulated this poorly. The reason I use a string, with quotes, is because I put this string directly into the ng-show with two-way data-binding. It works fine if I manually change the string variable in my controller, and the toggle function changes the variable accordingly, but the table isn't updating it's view.  I'm aware that this sollution seems quite weird.

Answer (score 0):

ng-show's don't take parameters with {{}} instead, use ng-show="solvedStatus"

And! Why are you booleans in your controller written as strings...

```
        $scope.solvedStatus = "problem.solved === false";
```

What do you think this returns? When setting booleans, or any variable for that matter, you use one "=" problem.solved = false....